# Is this Ember Mixin going to Leak Memory like Sieve

Tags: ember.js, data-binding, ember-data

I've written this `Mixin` for my `AdminController` so that I can edit a Record's data. I'm collecting the model attributes into an array that is returned. I'm binding the value, but to do so I've added a reference to the model in each array item. I'm worried that doing this is going to leak memory. Ideally I can reference the model with some other (more global?) path.

Here is the Mixin:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    modelAttributes: function() {
        var model = this.get('model');
        var attrs = [];
        model.eachAttribute(name => {
            var obj = Ember.Object.create({
                // Possible memory leak because I've assigned the model inside a closure? 
                model: model,                           
                key: name,

                // This is connects the model attribute with the input
                // field in my template 
                valueBinding: ('model.'+name),
            });
            attrs.push(obj);
        });

        return attrs;
    }.property('model'),
});
```

This is how I'm utilizing the attributes in a template:

```
{{#each attr in modelAttributes}}
<tr>
    <th>{{attr.key}}</th>
    <td>{{input value=attr.value class="form-control"}}</td>
</tr>       
{{/each}}
```

Code review and other ideas are welcome!!

Answer (score 2):

Nope, circular references/closure won't create memory leaks by themselves.  In your example the function is anonymous and will be collected once it no longer is referenced.  The moment the model is no longer reference by anyone is the moment it will be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Can you think of a better way to create this binding without referencing the model in each and every object in the array?